# Does Trump have the right to waive a jury trial and request a bench trial in the classified documents case?

Tags: criminal-law, jury, criminal-procedure, federal-courts, bench-trial

In the Federal criminal case against Donald Trump in the Mar-a-Lago classified documents case, does former president Trump have the ability to waive a jury trial and request a bench trial?

Given Aileen Cannon's history in cases involving the defendant, and potential bias towards the person who appointed her would this be a good legal strategy on his part?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the right to a jury trial is waiveable, in order to have a bench trial in a federal district court, [the court and prosecutor generally must agree](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/right_to_jury_trial).

> before any waiver can become effective, the consent of government counsel and the sanction of the court must be had
>
> (*Patton v. United States*, [281 U.S. 276, 312](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/usrep/usrep281/usrep281276/usrep281276.pdf#page=37) (1930))

This is codified in Rule 23(a) of the [Federal Rules of Criminal Procedure](https://www.uscourts.gov/sites/default/files/rules-of-criminal-procedure.pdf).

However, just because the waiver *can* be (and generally *is*) conditioned on governmental consent, some courts have nonetheless allowed the defendant's request for a bench trial despite the lack of consent from the government. See e.g. *United States v. Panteleakis*, [422 F. Supp. 247](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-panteleakis) (D.R.I. 1976) (a trial against multiple defendants that would require considering "approximately 1,000 exhibits," "over a three month period," with some evidence admissible against some defendants while *in*admissible against others; and the government did not try to "rebut the inference that substantial prejudice [in a trial by jury] is practically impossible to avoid under these circumstances").

This possibility appears to have been left open by the Supreme Court in *Singer v. United States*, [380 U.S. 24](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/usrep/usrep380/usrep380024/usrep380024.pdf) (1964):

> We need not determine in this case whether there might be some circumstances where a defendant's reasons for wanting to be tried by a judge alone are so compelling that the Government's insistence on trial by jury would result in the denial to a defendant of an impartial trial.

Comment: This is generally the correct answer under [Rule 23](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcrmp/rule_23), but note that there are outlier cases where the court has proceeded to a bench trial over the government's objection. *See*, *e.g.*, [*United States v. Panteleakis*, 422 F. Supp. 247, 250 (D.R.I. 1976)](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-panteleakis) (“The Court finds the government's refusal to grant consent unreasonable and arbitrary, and feels compelled to grant the defendants' motion.”)